# jQuery: animate() method with delay issue on scroll function

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate the height of this menu with jQuery according to the window scroll. On scroll down it works fine, but when scrolling up there's a delay in the animation that I don't understand. The code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('.menu').animate({height:'40px'});
     }
    else
     {
      $('.menu').animate({height:'100px'});
     }
 });
```

Besides, if I use the methods fadeOut() and fadeIn(), the code works fine. Why?

Comment: At the moment when you are scrolling it fires the animate function multiply times, which I assume is a big part of the problem. Add a flag or some kind of class that you can check to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint of @drip, I managed to reach this solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (top > 0) {

        $(".menu").stop().animate({height: '50px'}, 100);
    } else {

        $(".menu").stop().animate({height: '100px'}, 100);
    }
})
```

The `stop()` method keeps the animation from being triggered several times